# Can't run onmousemove when mouse move in div tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:

javascript:

```
function bootstrap(id) {
   this.id = id;
   this.init = function() {
      document.getElementById(this.id).onmousemove = positionButton;
   }
   function positionButton(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
      if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
         cursor.x = e.pageX;
         cursor.y = e.pageY;
      } else {
         cursor.x = e.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) - document.documentElement.clientLeft;
         cursor.y = e.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) - document.documentElement.clientTop;
      }
      var elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
      elem.style.position = 'absolute';
      elem.style.top = cursor.y - 10 + 'px';
      elem.style.left = cursor.x - 30 + 'px';
   }
}
```

In html:

```
<div id="button" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 100; width:27px; height:20px; overflow:hidden">
test test
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>
var bootstrap = new bootstrap('button');
bootstrap.init();
</script>
```

When I run code, result not run event mousemove, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The style of the button.
Your code:

```
width:27px;height:20px;
```

I change to

```
width:60px;height:50px;
```

I try it on IE9.It works.

Answer (score 0):

Run this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antoninor/U9G78/6) that I created with a slight modification of your code:

```
    function bootstrap(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.init = function() {
            document.getElementById(this.id).onmousemove = positionButton;
        };

        function positionButton(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var cursor = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            };
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                cursor.x = e.pageX;
                cursor.y = e.pageY;
            } else {
                cursor.x = e.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) - document.documentElement.clientLeft;
                cursor.y = e.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) - document.documentElement.clientTop;
            }
            var elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
            elem.style.position = 'absolute';
            elem.style.top = cursor.y - 10 + 'px';
            elem.style.left = cursor.x - 30 + 'px';
        }
    }

var bootstrap = new bootstrap('button');
bootstrap.init();​
```

It works correctly with Chrome, Safari and FFX.

Have you any error in your browser console?

Is script.js correctly downloaded?

What browser are you using?